# Getting Latitude, Longitude values from folium map on mouse click to python script

Tags: python, pyqt5, folium

How can I get Latitude, Longitude values from folium map on mouse click to python script. I can show it on map but ı can not get it

```
class MapPage(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.ui = Ui_MAP()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)


        self.m = folium.Map(
            location=[38.370862, 27.201039], zoom_start=100, control_scale=True
        )
        self.m.add_child(folium.LatLngPopup())#I am trying get these coordinates. How can I do this?
        self.data = io.BytesIO()
        self.m.save(self.data, close_file=False)
        self.ui.webView.setHtml(self.data.getvalue().decode())
```